# Computing $\lim_{x\to -\infty}x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(x)\right)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> What is the value of $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(x)\right)$$?

Comment: Is this it: $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(x)\right)$$??

Comment: @Dave yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the limit as $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\pi/2+\arctan(x)}{1/x}$$ then use L'Hopital's rule (since $\arctan(x)\to -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$). Recall, $$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: this one totally worked and the limit at the end equals -1 but the problem is we're not really allowed to use l'hopital's rule, they haven't taught us that but I know that it's really efficient. So i'll try to solve it in another way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $x < 0$,
$$ \pi/2 + \arctan(x) = - \arctan(1/x). $$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} x\left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan(x) \right) = - \lim_{x \to -\infty} x \arctan(1/x) = - \lim_{u \to 0_-} \frac{\arctan{u}}{u}.$$ 
(substituting $u = 1/x$ in the last step.) Take it from there.

Comment: Can I ask you though, is your first statement a property ? Because I don't know about it. (i'm in high school by the way)

Comment: @Abbkey:  Yes, it's an identity obeyed by the arctangent function.  It's actually not too hard to prove a slightly different identity $x > 0$:  Draw a right triangle with legs $x$ and $1$.  The two acute angles will be $\arctan(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$.  But the two acute angles add to $\pi/2$;  thus, $\arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x) = \pi/2$ for all $x > 0$.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to extend this argument to $x < 0$.

Comment: I just used the fact that arctan is an odd function and it worked. Thank you for the identity.